# Why is a cast exception fatal in Java?

Tags: java, oop

According to [this](https://thesocietea.org/2015/11/programming-concepts-static-vs-dynamic-type-checking/) article:

> In contrast to static type checking, dynamic type checking may cause a program to fail at runtime due to type errors. In some programming languages, it is possible to anticipate and recover from these failures – either by error handling or poor type safety. In others, type checking errors are considered fatal.

Java is an example where type checking errors are fatal. Why is Java (and maybe most static typed languages) so strict that it fails at runtime if a type error occurs? Let's say you upcast object A (actual type `int`) to type `Object`, and downcast to `String`. Compile-time checking will pass, but the runtime type check will fail with a fatal exception. This seems harsh, as it's not like an `illegalArgumentException` where the program literally *cannot* proceed (an invalid cast loses type safety but shouldn't be impossible). It would seem to me like the most optimal situation would be to throw a warning and then fail fatally if trying to call, say, `String` method `indexOf` on the integer object. Is there a reason for Java actually failing to proceed at runtime when trying to perform this invalid cast?

Comment: Generally speaking, failing _fast_ is better for server programming than failing at the last possible moment.  If you think a thing is a `String` and it isn't, it's better to fail as soon as possible to make it easier to track down where the bad object came from.  If you wait until the last minute, it just makes it that much harder to figure out where things went wrong.

Comment: Ermm ... a ClassCastException is NOT fatal in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Java is an example where type checking errors are fatal.

No it isn't. You can catch them.

> Why is Java (and maybe most static typed languages) so strict that it fails at runtime if a type error occurs?

Because that's what 'static typing' means; ditto 'strict typing'.

> Let's say you upcast object A (actual type int) to type Object, and downcast to String. Compile-time checking will pass, but the runtime type check will fail with a fatal exception.

No it won't. It will fail with a `ClassCastException.`

> This seems harsh, as it's not like an illegalArgumentException where the program literally cannot proceed (an invalid cast loses type safety but shouldn't be impossible).

But it is impossible. The cast cannot proceed. The way the object code is generated assumes so.

> It would seem to me like the most optimal situation would be to throw a warning

It throws a `ClassCastException.`

> and then fail fatally if trying to call, say, String method indexOf on the integer object.

Well it doesn't do that.

> Is there a reason for Java actually failing to proceed at runtime when trying to perform this invalid cast?

The implementation is designed around the fact that the exception occurs.

Comment: "But it is impossible. The cast cannot proceed. The way the object code is generated assumes so." Can you elaborate on that more?

Comment: Too broad to answer here.

Comment: well as a followup question: is a cast successful only if every method in the declared type is defined in the reference type?

Comment: @rb612 It fails if the object isn't an instance of the target class or interface,

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan Your comment is also entertaining, but it doesn't add any actual value here. If you have a new question, ask it *as a question*. Not here in a comment where nobody will ever see it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not done like that because there is no benefit to what you're suggesting.

If you had code that could continue working in those situations, then your code is bad and superfluous, because the cast wasn't really necessary, as you're not doing anything specific with that type.

Typically languages are not designed to cater for unnecessary code.

There are lots of disadvantages, most notably performance: it wouldn't be possible to compile to machine code efficiently in a language that did what you describe.

Statically typed languages are typically faster than dynamically typed languages because knowing the type up-front makes many optimizations possible that wouldn't be possible otherwise.

Any what you are suggesting would make the language dynamically typed.

Comment: The benefit I see for what I'm suggesting is in situations where you'd want to duck type - if there's no common interface between two classes. Why is this functionality not available in statically typed languages?

Comment: @rb612 Because that’s what ‘statically typed’ *means.*

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is to ensure that the programmer can locate the problem and fix it, ensuring that the software is correct.  If you ignore a casting problem until you dereference, it could be too far down the road to track back easily.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks! I get that casting an object to an incompatible type is wrong, but does the program actually encounter an error that makes it impossible to proceed? After all, the declared type is just a reference to the actual object and nothing else.

Comment: Well, the answer is yes, that there is an error that makes it impossible to proceed.  Since a cast fails, it implies that the methods defined for the object types do not line up, so future calls to them from the casted object will likely fail.

Comment: That's right - they'll likely fail. But this is what's always bothered me: future calls will likely fail but without calling any of those undefined methods, no harm no foul right?

Comment: Yes, but only if you're in a weakly typed language.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on that? I thought it would have to do with it being static typed, not strong typed.

Comment: Ah, I think you may be right.  Instead of weakly, I should have said dynamically typed, I think.

Comment: Nope! You're actually absolutely right. It's strong type checking.